# Audio Element not working in Safari 5.1

Tags: php, javascript, audio, safari

I have searched everywhere for my problem and found some answers but didn't seem to work when I implemented it.

Here is my simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Audio Test</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
    play_audio();
  });

  $(document).on("click", "#play-btn", function(){
    play_audio();
  });

  function play_audio(){
    var notify = document.getElementById("sound-notification");
    notify.play();
  }

</script>

</head>

<body>

<audio id="sound-notification" src="beep.ogg"></audio>

<button id="play-btn">Play</button>

hello world

</body>
</html>
```

There are two ways that I generate the audio sound, right after the page loads and when the user clicks on the button.

Everything works fine in FF and Chrome but not in Safari(i have version 5.1.7)

Im not sure if I have done anything wrong or what.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know if safari supports ogg, I don't think it does.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I have tried the format, m4a, wav but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have quicktime installed?

Comment: Yes, I have. But shouldn't it be not dependent with quicktime?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using html5 doctype to make the page interpret this as HTML5 document.

```
<!doctype html>
```

and not what you have used like.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
$(document).on("click", "#play-btn", function(){
    play_audio();
  });

  function play_audio(){
    var notify = document.getElementById("sound-notification");
    notify.play();
  }

});

</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried your suggestion but it doesn't have any changes. It still works in FF and Chrome but not in Safari. Thanks.

Comment: check my updated code, it should work. you are not calling play_audio(); function properly.

Comment: i have tried to replace my code with the one you created but it still doesn't work.

Comment: try adding type="audio/ogg" to your audio tag

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working...

```
<audio id="sound-notification">
  <source scr="beep.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></source>
  <source src="beep.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
</audio>
```

Hope this will help anyone.

Comment: how does it work, i wouldn't able to make it working on my safari browser. Windows 7 x64.

Comment: please check the code above for details on how to implement it.

Comment: I'm using Safari 5.1.7 (Windows 8.1) and this does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me adding click sound on  elements in all browsers on Drupal:

```
    var snd = new Audio(Drupal.settings["basePath"] + "sites/all/themes/your_theme/click.ogg");
    var sndSafari = new Audio(Drupal.settings["basePath"] + "sites/all/themes/your_theme/click.mp3");

    var is_safari = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1;

    jQuery('body a').click(function(){
         if(is_safari){
            sndSafari.play();
         }else{
            snd.play();
         }
    });
```

---

This is extra info just in case somebody needs it:

Firefox 3.5+ >>  Supports .ogg, .wav

IE9+  >> Supports .mp3

Chrome 6+ >>  Supports .ogg, .mp3, .mp4

Safari 5+  >> Supports .mp3, .mp4, .wav

Opera 10.5+ >> Supports .ogg, .wav

Make sure to add your sound path correctly (i was using drupal api)